# How to execute mongoose queries immediately and wait for them with Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I'm just getting used to promises and I want to add an additional ObjectId reference to a table. I use this code:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');

mongoose.connect(config.get("DBUrl"), {useMongoClient: true});
mongoose.set('debug', true);

require('../model/AnnotationRequest');
require('../model/Website');

const AnnotationRequest = mongoose.model('AnnotationRequest');
const Website = mongoose.model('Website');

foo(function () {
    console.log('done');
});

function foo(done) {

    Website.find()
        .then(function (websites) {
            if (!websites) console.error('could not find any websites');

            AnnotationRequest.find({website: {$exists: false}})
                .then(function (annotationRequests) {

                    let jobs = [];

                    for (let k = 0; k < annotationRequests.length; k++) {
                        let found = false;

                        for (let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
                            let websiteAnnotations = websites[i].annotations;

                            for (let o = 0; o < websiteAnnotations.length; o++) {

                                if (websiteAnnotations[o].equals(annotationRequests[k].annotation)) {
                                    found = true;
                                    annotationRequests[k].website = websites[i];
                                    jobs.push(
                                        annotationRequests[k].save()
                                            .then(function (res) {
                                                console.log("success saving", res._id);
                                            }).catch(function (err) {
                                                console.error(err);
                                                done(err);
                                            })
                                    );
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (found) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Promise.all(jobs).then(
                        function () {
                            done();
                        }
                    ).catch(function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
                });
        });
}
```

The first save query is reported to be started at the Promise.all statement. Should the queries not be executed immediately after the first `.save()` statement? How can I start them immediately?

The other Problem is that with 200k entries this code takes 2 hours. On the server we have > 2M entries. Not sure if it will work. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: To perform massive inserting i can strong suggest you to take a look at bulk operations (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node runs single threaded so if you have 200k loop all save statements waits until your sync for code executes and finish.

Try to use async module to make your code more async friendly.
https://caolan.github.io/async/

Try this code but this code has same bug with yours. Id more then one websites has same annotation, your set first found, mine probably last found.

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const async = require('async');


mongoose.connect(config.get("DBUrl"), {useMongoClient: true});
mongoose.set('debug', true);

require('../model/AnnotationRequest');
require('../model/Website');

const AnnotationRequest = mongoose.model('AnnotationRequest');
const Website = mongoose.model('Website');

foo(function () {
    console.log('done');
});

function foo(done) {

    const pageSize= 10000;

    async.parallel([function(callback) {

        Website.find().then( function(websites) {
            callback(null, websites);
        }).catch(callback);

    },function(callback) {
        AnnotationRequest.count({website: {$exists: false}}).then( function(count) {
            callback(null, count);
        }).catch(callback);
    }], function(err, results) {

        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        const websites = results[0];
        const annotationRequestsCount = results[1];

        let websiteAnnotationMap = {};

        websites.forEach(function (website) {
            website.annotations.forEach(function (annotation) {
                websiteAnnotationMap[annotation] = website;
            });
        });


        var skip = 0;

        async.during(
            function (callback) {
                return callback(null, skip < annotationRequestsCount);
            },
            function (callback) {

                AnnotationRequest.find({website: {$exists: false}},  { skip: skip, limit: pageSize })
                    .then( function(annotationRequests) {

                        skip += pageSize;

                        async.each(annotationRequests, function(annotationRequest, eachCallback) {

                            let website = websiteAnnotationMap[annotationRequest.annotation];
                            if(website) {
                                annotationRequest.website = website;
                                annotationRequest.save().then(function () {
                                    eachCallback();
                                }).catch(eachCallback);

                            } else {
                                eachCallback();
                            }
                        }, callback);
                }).catch(callback);
            },
            done
        );


    });
}
```

Comment: Just tried with production database: `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: You you mentioned 2M record so you need to implement some paging.